# Manipulate one big file with threads

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-synchronization

I have a big file with sorted elements that looks like this

```
a 1 1 
a 2 1   
a 3 5
b 2 3 
b 3 5
...
```

I would like to create the inverted index of this file so it would look like this

```
a 1 1 2 1 3 5
b 2 3 3 5
...
```

Now i have already done that. My question has to do with threads, i am really new in thread programming and any help would be much appreciated. I would like to know if it is possible to create this index with multiple threads that will work on the same file and if it is a pseudo algorithm or a link to a documentation of what i have to read to learn how would be nice too.

Thanks!

Comment: To use multiple threads, you have to identify which tasks you can perform concurrently and independently. Note: you cannot simply read a text file concurrently as you need to read one line to work out where the next one is. (There is more complex ways of doing this with random access but it is rarely done AFAIK)  I suggest you profile you application to see where you CPU bottlenecks are and work if these tasks can be performed by multiple threads.

Comment: You say you have a big file. Have you already read the file in ? If so is there a data type you are currently using to represent those elements ?

Comment: Your example output makes it look like all you want to do is group all the "a" rows into one "a" row, all the "b" rows into one "b" row, etc.  I'd be surprised if a multi-threaded process could do that job any faster than a single-threaded process.

Comment: Also, I don't know what your data are supposed to mean, but that doesn't look like an inverted index to me.  If you have an "index" (e.g., a `Map<Key, List<Value>>`), then an "inverted index" is a `Map<Value, List<Key>>`.

Comment: There's no reason to suppose threading will add any value here.